# I receive an array of string and want to access a hashmap based on the string received in in the array

Tags: java, hashmap

```
 given String arr[] = {"hashmap1", "hashmap2"};
 Hashmap<String,Integer> hashmap1;
 Hashmap<String,Integer> hashmap2;
```

How can I do this:

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   System.out.println(arr[i].get("value")); 

 // basically, arr[i] is the hashmap name and I want to access it
 }
```

I've tried to put all `hashmaps` in an `arraylist` and go from there but that didn't work either.

```
for(int i=0;i<cardNames.length;i++){

            boolean tmp = cardNames[i].containsKey(storeType);
```

I get this error:

> error: cannot find symbol
>                       boolean tmp = cardNames[i].get(storeType);
>                                                     ^
>         symbol:   method get(String)
>         location: class String

Comment: what is cardNames and storType here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you can do is have a Map for all the maps you have with names as key.

Something like this:

```
 Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> superHashMap = new HashMap<>();
 String arr[] = {"hashmap1", "hashmap2"};
 Hashmap<String,Integer> hashmap1;
 Hashmap<String,Integer> hashmap2;

 superHashMap.put("hashmap1", hashmap1);
 superHashMap.put("hashmap2", hashmap2);

 How can I do this:
 for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   // This shall contain the desired hashMap that you would need for further processing.
   Map<String, Integer> mapYouNeedToAccess = superHashMap.get(arr[i]);
 }
```